# What happens to methods of serialised PHP classes?

Tags: php, oop, serialization

Can someone explain what happens to methods when a php class is serialised? I don't see them in output when I dump or serialize the class, and after creating an instance a reference(?) to the method seems to be available when serializing from a string.

This is the code giving surprising output:

```
class ticket { 
    public $film="Killer bananas 3";

    public function invalidate(){
        echo '*punch*';
    }
}

$myticket = new ticket();

var_dump($myticket);
var_dump(serialize($myticket));

echo "output #1: ";
echo $myticket->invalidate().PHP_EOL;

$temp = serialize($myticket);
$newticket = unserialize($temp);
echo "output #2: ";
echo $newticket->invalidate().PHP_EOL;

$ticketfromstring = unserialize('O:6:"ticket":1:{s:4:"film";s:28:"Attack of the killer bananas";}');
echo "output #3: ";
echo $ticketfromstring->invalidate().PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
me@box:~# php -f /home/ekomi/includes/classes/class.test.php
object(ticket)#1 (1) {
  ["film"]=>
  string(16) "Killer bananas 3"
}
string(52) "O:6:"ticket":1:{s:4:"film";s:16:"Killer bananas 3";}"
output #1: *punch*
output #2: *punch*
output #3: *punch*
```

This behaviour is strange (especially the last one!)

Note that I already tested json_encode and it only gives the properties (even though a JSON could contain a function) and throws an error when trying to call the method.

Comment: What behavior did you expect? You are calling a method which returns a string literal.

Comment: I was surprised the method was available at all. Auto-creation of objects when unserialized in a namespace isn't well-documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization saves to string only object attributes because that is all we need. All methods are defined in PHP code.

When you try to deserialize object, PHP will look for its class. Then will create object from that class with attributes from deserialized string.

You can check it by serializing object in one script and deserializing it in another (without used class definition). PHP will show error because deserialization will be impossible.